# *only* Safari hangs up executing the rest of my code when a file is upload. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, file, safari, upload

This works just fine in any browser, however, in safari the visibilities don't change until AFTER the file has uploaded or the user hits "stop" in the browser toolbar.

Why oh why is safari the only browser to act this way? 
What can I do to fix it?

EDIT: Okay, so I trimmed down my code to just the basic elements, and it *STILL* acts funny in safari. I cannot figure out what's going on for the life of me. The supplied code is incredibly simplified now... yet, it still *refuses* to update the visibility options until the file has finished uploading or the send button is pressed without a file in it. Every other browser updates the visibility settings during the upload.
Please, anybody, help!

### HTML + JS in head

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>Our Industry Alpha 0.01</title>
      <script>
      function formcheck() {
        document.getElementById('i_submit').style.visibility='hidden';
        document.getElementById('patience').style.visibility='visible';
      }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
         <input type="file" required>
         <input type="submit" style="visibility:visible;" value="Send" id="i_submit" onclick="formcheck();">
       </form>
       <div id="patience" style="visibility:hidden;">... UPLOADING ...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console for errors? Are there any?

Comment: Might be worth trying to distill this whole code down to the most minimal one required to reproduce the problem. Chances are you'll solve your own problem in the process.

Comment: I have checked the console, but nothing comes up as an error. console spits out that the visibility changes have occurred, yet they don't take place in the browser display until the file has finished or until the user hits "stop" in the toolbar